# Duplicate Symbol Linker error XCode 3.2.5 -- linker seems to reference same file in different ways

Tags: iphone, xcode, linker, three20, ld

I get the following error:

> ld: duplicate symbol
>   _TTCreateNonRetainingArray in /Users/macuser/Dropbox/DFJ/three20/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20Core.a(TTGlobalCore.o)
>   and
>   ../three20/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20Core.a(TTGlobalCore.o)
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   Command
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.2
>   failed with exit code 1

It seems to be referring to the same .o from an absolute and relative paths.

> Ld
>   build/DFJ.build/Debug-iphoneos/DFJ.build/Objects-normal/armv6/DFJ
>   normal armv6 cd
>   /Users/macuser/Dropbox/DFJ/DFJ setenv
>   IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 3.2 setenv
>   PATH
>   "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.2
>   -arch armv6 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk
>   -L/Users/macuser/Dropbox/DFJ/DFJ/build/Debug-iphoneos
>   -F/Users/macuser/Dropbox/DFJ/DFJ/build/Debug-iphoneos
>   -F/Users/macuser/Dropbox/DFJ/DFJ/../../../Downloads/gdata-objectivec-client-1.11.0/Source/build/Debug
>   -filelist /Users/macuser/Dropbox/DFJ/DFJ/build/DFJ.build/Debug-iphoneos/DFJ.build/Objects-normal/armv6/DFJ.LinkFileList
>   -dead_strip -force_load ../three20/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20Core.a
>   -force_load ../three20/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20UICommon.a
>   -force_load ../three20/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20Launcher.a
>   -force_load ../three20/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20UINavigator.a
>   -force_load ../three20/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20.a
>   -force_load ../three20/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20UI.a
>   -force_load ../three20/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20Network.a
>   -force_load ../three20/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20Style.a
>   -all_load -miphoneos-version-min=3.2 /Users/macuser/Dropbox/DFJ/three20/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20Core.a
>   /Users/macuser/Dropbox/DFJ/three20/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20UICommon.a
>   /Users/macuser/Dropbox/DFJ/three20/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20Launcher.a
>   /Users/macuser/Dropbox/DFJ/three20/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20UINavigator.a
>   /Users/macuser/Dropbox/DFJ/three20/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20.a
>   /Users/macuser/Dropbox/DFJ/three20/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20UI.a
>   /Users/macuser/Dropbox/DFJ/three20/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20Network.a
>   /Users/macuser/Dropbox/DFJ/three20/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20Style.a
>   -framework QuartzCore -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework
>   CoreGraphics -lsqlite3.0 -framework
>   MobileCoreServices -lxml2 -framework
>   Security -framework
>   SystemConfiguration -framework OpenAL
>   -framework CoreAudio -framework AudioToolbox -o
>   /Users/macuser/Dropbox/DFJ/DFJ/build/DFJ.build/Debug-iphoneos/DFJ.build/Objects-normal/armv6/DFJ
>
> ld: duplicate symbol
>   _TTCreateNonRetainingArray in /Users/macuser/Dropbox/DFJ/three20/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20Core.a(TTGlobalCore.o)
>   and
>   ../three20/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20Core.a(TTGlobalCore.o)
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   Command
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.2
>   failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the last message of the developer of Three20 [here](http://groups.google.com/group/three20/browse_thread/thread/60630131d9961416). Basically, download the newest Three20 sources and follow closely the steps described in their [README](https://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/master/README.mdown).

If you are following a Three20 tutorial that is not coming from the developer, chances are it's outdated.